# I have a url stored in a variable, how do I open the link in that variable in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$_SESSION['link'] = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

This code gets the link I am currently on and stores it. How do you open that link? The following line doesn't open it.

```
header("Location: $_SESSION['link']");
```

Comment: did you ever echo your $_SESSION['link']

Comment: Does it print any error? Have you started session? Isnt there something like "headers already sent"?

Comment: `header()` wants to be before any output. Even `HTML`. Also put an `exit;` after it. Because the script runs on anyway else.

Comment: Try this one may help : header("Location: ".$_SESSION['link']);

Comment: When in a double quoted string literal remove the quotes around the array occurance `header("Location: $_SESSION[link]");` or use `{}` like `header("Location: {$_SESSION['link']}");`

Comment: @abrar Thank you that worked. But I am meant to have an error message appear to the user before that page reopens and now my error message is ignored (`echo '<script type = "text/javascript">alert("No numbers allowed")</script>';`)  Is there any fix for that?

Comment: No you cannot. As I said before.